# Imported site doesn't displays CSS styles

Tags: 7, theming

I imported a site from pantheon to my localhost to work on it. The site pulls up just fine, however, it has no CSS styles at all. Its plain HTML through and through. Also i'm getting 30+ of these type of errors:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil739F.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1940 of C:\wamp\vhosts\cbirc\includes\file.inc).
The file could not be created.
```

How do I get the styling added back to the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've properly configured **Temporary Directory** inside **Admin => Configuration => Media => File System**, and check if "Public File System" and "Temporary Directory" have valid permissions to them. Once confirmed, clear site cache.

If not required you can also disable CSS Compression by navigating to "Admin => Configuration => Performance". So they will be accessed directly for there original location.

Comment: Okay this is going to sound weird but try my best to explain. I went to the location suggested and the tmp was set as "/tmp". I removed the "/" so it became "tmp" only. Now here is the weird part.

In firefox I get a completly white blank screen. NOTHING shows up. 
In google chrome, the issue is fixed! The css styles are back and displaying properly!

However, i'm getting fatal error messages from time to time that say "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted".

Comment: It might be cached in Firefox, you can try opening the url in Private browser window in Firefox and see if you're still receiving same error. If still facing the same issue, you can have a look at [Blank pages or "white screen of death" (WSOD)](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) for debugging or check Apache2 error logs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Set the temporary file directory in File System. Then Go to either Performance clear cache or use drush cc within your site folder on command line